TwinCat 3 Code Architecture/FBs integrations
I'm working on learning OOP coding for TwinCat 3. I'd like to transfer and optimize the code my company has from AB Studio 5000 to ST TwinCat 3. The industry I normally work on is Material Handling (conveyors, high speed sortation, etc).
Since I'm coming from Studio 5000 environment, I'm used to GlobalVariables. I've been reading it is a bad practice to use many GlobalVariables and I'd like to avoid it to keep a good practice from the beginning.
My question is, if I have differente FBs and Methods executing pieces of code. How can I share the outcome of those codes between programs. Example.
Currently, I have a FB for my conveyance control and a FB for my PE jam logic. If my conveyor is running and my PE gets blocked for x amount of time I should get a jammed output that should stop the conveyor. How can I share the variables: conveyor running, jammed, etc?
I'd appreciate the help with this.
I've been reading about interfaces but not quite sure how they'll be integrated into the FBs. Not sure if interfaces will be right path or if there might be a best path to follow.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

First of all, avoidance of global variables is, indeed, a good idea. It kills code re-usability, and often leads to ugly dependencies. It only makes sense to have global variables for data that is fundamentally unique (i.e. may only exist in a single copy in any running system). There is not a lot of that.
There is no single answer to this question. But, generally speaking, at least one of your function blocks will need some way to be aware of at least one other function block. The details are beyond the scope of a quick answer, but maybe I can help you start your research.
Here are some pointers (pun intended) for achieving that :

One function block may contain a pointer (POINTER TO) or a reference (REFERENCE TO) another function block. This pointer/reference must be initialized when your system starts. One clean way to achieve that is to declare an FB_Init method with an argument having the type REFERENCE TO SOME_FB, and use this argument to initialize a variable inside your function block using the REF= reference operator. Once you have done that, you can use this reference as if it were the function block itself including to access its outputs). It is not an independent copy, it is, as the name implies, a reference. This method can broadly be called "reference injection".

You may also declare a method (routine) in one of your function blocks that you will call as needed (probably once per cycle, directly or indirectly from your MAIN), passing it whatever data needs to be shared, or a REFERENCE TO as previously introduced.

Interfaces make it possible to define types that can be implemented by many function blocks. For instance, you may have a PUMP interface, a function blocks that IMPLEMENTS PUMP (look for the IMPLEMENTS keyword in the documentation for where it goes, and what it does). Passing a function block instance using an interface implicitly creates a reference, you do not need to add REFERENCE TO to its type. An interface type can be used to replace a function block type in both of the above scenarios.


Please note that when passing pointers/references as part of an FB_Init call, order of initialization becomes critical, and it takes a while to develop a good understanding of the order in which everything in a system initializes (especially when using inheritance). Method called (directly or indirectly) from the MAIN program are not affected by that, because cyclic execution only starts after the FB_Init calls have completed and all instances have been initialized.
